# Validation is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one asp content page.Its contain many controls like dropdownlist,textbox etc.All controls are inside a div tag.I gave required field validator for all my drop down list.i have one SAVE button that reside inside another div tag.I gave SAVE button cause validation true.But my problem is that, the validator is not working and the page.Isvalid property is true.What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You probably should post some code too. Without any code is hard to help you out.

Comment: In way you asked I can tell one think - your code does not working ;)
Show your code pleas.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have set the ControlToValidate property to the DropDownList id. Also you need to set the InitialValue property on the RequiredFieldValidator when validating a DropDownList. This basically just tells the Validator which item is the intial value (which will throw a validation error when it is selected).

Hope this helps,
Neil